# How can I use html styles in strings with format arguments?

Tags: java, android

In my app, I'd like to define a format string in strings.xml that looks like this (note the `<b>...</b>` tags):

```
<string name="location"><b>Location:</b> %1$s</string>
```

And then use [getString(int, Object...)](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/String.html#format%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...%29) to substitute in a format argument:

```
String formattedString = getString(R.string.location, "Edmonton, AB");
```

This produces a value of `"Location: Edmonton, AB"`. I'd like to get a value of `"<b>Location:</b> Edmonton, AB"`.

Is there some way of doing this using string formats in strings.xml without splitting it up into two strings?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

From the [docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource.html):

> Sometimes you may want to create a styled text resource that is also
>   used as a format string. Normally, this won't work because the
>   String.format(String, Object...) method will strip all the style
>   information from the string. The work-around to this is to write the
>   HTML tags with escaped entities, which are then recovered with
>   fromHtml(String), after the formatting takes place.

For example:

```
<resources>
  <string name="welcome_messages">Hello, %1$s! You have &lt;b>%2$d new messages&lt;/b>.</string>
</resources>
```

Make sure to escape the text you are passing in `String.format()`

```
String escapedUsername = TextUtils.htmlEncode(username);
Resources res = getResources();
String text = String.format(res.getString(R.string.welcome_messages), escapedUsername, mailCount);
CharSequence styledText = Html.fromHtml(text);
```

Comment: @GregInYEG - Happens to the best of us. My pleasure.

Comment: Just be aware of the fact that TextUtils.htmlEncode() method does not replace ' ' (space) with '&#160;'. This is causing troubles in my case (I'm using mailto: hyperlink with subject and body parameters). Otherwise the solution above works great.

Answer (score 1):

Use String.Format. e.g.

```
  <string name="location"><![CDATA[<b>Location:</b> %s]]></string>

String formattedString = String.Format(getString(R.string.location), "Edmonton, AB");
```

Comment: The string in your example doesn't contain styles. If it did, the call to getString(R.string.location) would strip them out.

Comment: I thought the point was to format a string which is what my example does. Add the format characters as extra parameters to the format method.

Comment: String.format(getString(R.string.location), "Edmonton, AB") returns the same thing as getString(R.string.location, "Edmonton, AB"). Neither preserve styles like <b>...</b> in the string from strings.xml. @iPaulPro's answer points to the android documentation that explains if I want to use both styles and format arguments, I need to escape the styles and use Html.fromHtml(...).

Comment: You need to escape your string resources. I have amended my answer above. (Did not realise the Html codes were the point of the question)